# How to set default database values

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I'm trying to set up the default database values as follows, but I get:

error: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException` for:

```
@Column(name = "dateOfBirth", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable=false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOfBirth;
```

AND...

error: `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""` for:

```
@Column(name = "zip", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable=false, columnDefinition = "bigint(20) default 0")
private long zip;
```

What is the correct way for setting up the default values for `Date` and `long`?

Comment: How to diagnose:  Pare the annotation down to just one entry, and add them one by one until you get your exception.  That will at least tell you which clause is giving your heartburn.

Comment: It is easier to set default values in database definition directly

Answer (score 0):

In both cases you need to remove this attribute:

```
nullable=true
```

When the DB will get a NULL value it will apply the DEFAULT anyway.

Answer (score 0):

How about initializing you attributes with default values in Java code :

```
@Column(name = "dateOfBirth", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable=false, columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
private Date dateOfBirth = new Date(); // or however you like to initialize this value.
```

And

```
@Column(name = "zip", insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable=false, columnDefinition = "bigint(20) default 0")
private long zip = 1001L;
```